# Python & Matplotlib: How to create colored density plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can create a probability density plot in 3d by

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z.T, rstride=1, cstride=1,
    facecolors=cm.jet(N),
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
```

Here, `x y` is the coordiante, `z` is the value of probability density(i.e `z = f(x,y)`). This would render a plot like this:

[image]

However, I want to take a look at it in the panel, to plot something like this:
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you already looked into the demos for contour plots?

Comment: @cel you mean this?: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

Comment: yes, for example. There are many more in the matplotlib documentation. See also the demos for [`matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf)

Comment: @cel and I find this very helpful https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#contour-plots